# Treating a part of program as data in Racket

Tags: racket

I must say that I don't know really know how to call what I'm looking for, so perhaps the title isn't that accurate.

I have a program that plots some points. The `generate-list` function produces a list of n (x,y) coordinates and `get-points` produces another list that has every x (from (x,y)) divisible by n.
I can definitely call `points` how many times I need, but I'm trying to reduce the process by writing the `points` function only once).

```
#lang racket
(require plot)

(define (generate-list n)
  (if (= n 0)
      empty
      (cons (list (random 0 100) (random 0 100))
            (generate-list (- n 1)))))

(define (get-points lst n)
  (if (empty? lst)
      empty
      (if (= (remainder (caar lst) n) 0)
          (cons (car lst) (get-points (cdr lst) n))
          (get-points (cdr lst) n))))

(plot (list
       (axes 0 0)
       (points (get-points (generate-list 1000) 2)
               #:color 2)
       (points (get-points (generate-list 1000) 3)
               #:color 3)
       (points (get-points (generate-list 1000) 4)
               #:color 4)
       (points (get-points (generate-list 1000) 5)
               #:color 5)))
```

Bellow is an example that doesn't produce anything useful, but I'm looking for something that simplifies the code in a similar manner.

```
(plot (list
       (axes 0 0)
       (for ([i (in-range 2 5)])
         (points (get-points (generate-list 1000) i)
                 #:color i))))
```

Of course any alternative that only writes the `points` function once would help a lot.

Comment: Try `for/list` instead of `for` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) instead of [`for`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for))) there:

```
(plot (list
       (axes 0 0)
       (for/list ([i (in-range 2 5)])
         (points (get-points (generate-list 1000) i)
                 #:color i))))
```

A [`for`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for))) loop throws away the values the body-expression produces on each iteration, while the [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29) loop puts them into a list, and returns the list so that all the points are included in the input to [`plot`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/plotting.html#(def._((lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt)._plot))).

(By the way, this nested list is okay because [`plot`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/plotting.html#(def._((lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt)._plot))) allows a `renderer-tree` as input.)

Comment: Oh boy, there are a lot of versions of for loops out there. Thanks for this!

Comment: If you don't mind a follow-up question can you give a little help with this? I've wrote something that produces an equivalent version of what I want to plot, however I don't know how to turn the quote into a list or something in order to plot it as `(plot to-plot)`. Here's the code: `(define to-plot '(axes 0 0))
(for ([i (in-range 2 5)])
  (set! to-plot (append (quasiquote((points (get-points (generate-list 100) (unquote i))
                                            #:color (unquote i)))) to-plot)))`

Comment: I would advise you not to use `'` quote when you want to make lists. Use things like `list`, `append`, `for/list`, `map`, `filter`, and so on, which are all expression-based, unlike `'` quote which is datum-based